# jQuery - Get child input based on name selector

Tags: jquery

I've got an onclick event which is calling a function, passing the current div:

```
<div onclick="deleteline($(this));">
```

In my deleteline function, how do I get a child of the parent of $(this) where the name contains Qty?

In this example I'm looking to get the ProdQty input box:

```
<div>
    <input id="PrdQty" type="hidden" value="1">
    <div onclick="deleteline($(this));">
</div>
```

EDIT:
This page is getting included multiple times within another page via an ajax call.
Therefore if I assign the clickable div an ID, it's going to cause a conflict after this code is injected into the parent for the 2nd time.

As a result, I've used the suggestions below, kept the inline onclick and I'm getting the qty using: sender.parent().find('input[id*="Qty"]')

Comment: It will be easier if you put your script inside a script block or file rather than inline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use CSS selectors for this in jQuery (http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

So your example would be:

```
$(this).siblings("input[id*='Qty']")
```

That will return all the inputs at the same level as $(this) which have 'Qty' in their id as an array.  If you only want the first one add .first() onto the end of the line, ie:

```
$(this).siblings("input[id*='Qty']").first()
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the jQuery event API?

```
// make it as specific as you need
$('div').click(function() {
    // do something
});
```

And you can use the [`.parent([selector])`](http://api.jquery.com/parent) function in jQuery to get the parent. And in this example you can use the [`.prev([selector])`](http://api.jquery.com/prev) function also to get the previous element.

Comment: Keep in mind, you can still use .filter to narrow down which divs you want.  For instance, inside this click event: `var divQty = $(this).children().filter(function(i) { return $(this).attr("name").indexOf("Qty") >= 0; });` or even ``var divQty = $(this).prev().filter(function(i) { return $(this).attr("name").indexOf("Qty") >= 0; });``

Answer (score 1):

```
   <div>
      <input id="PrdQty" type="hidden" value="1">
      <div id="getChild"></div>   // here I give an ID to you div.you can also  use class
   </div>


   // binding click event on #getChild div

    $('#getChild').on('click', function() {

       $(this).parent().find('input[id~="Qty"]');

    });
```

**OR:**

```
<div>
    <input id="PrdQty" type="hidden" value="1">
    <div onclick="deleteline(this);">
</div>


function deleteline($this) {
   $($this).parent().find('input[id~="Qty"]');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to remove the onclick from the HTML markup because i love to write it in a n [unobutrusive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) way. I would add a class name to the div to be act as the selector

```
<div>
  <input id="PrdQty" type="hidden" value="1">
  <div class="divtoCheck" />
</div>


$(function(){
    $(".divtoCheck").click(function(){
         var child=$(this).parent().find("input[id*='Qty']")
        alert(child.attr("id"));
    });

});
```

working sample http://jsfiddle.net/gKnf3/10/

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the [attribute contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) that jQuery offers.

Here's some code I fiddled: http://jsfiddle.net/luhn/RrczZ/

**Edit:**  All the other answers seem to be using the [attribute contains word selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/), which won't actually work....